# When is the initial form of a principal ideal generated by the initial form of the original ideal's generator?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, local-rings

$
\DeclareMathOperator{\init}{in}
\DeclareMathOperator{\gr}{gr}
\newcommand{\calO}{\mathcal{O}}
$Let $(R,\mathfrak{m})$ be a Noetherian local ring and $\gr_{\mathfrak{m}}(R)=\bigoplus_{i=0}^\infty\mathfrak{m}^i/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1}$ be the associated graded ring. For $f\in R$, the initial form of $f$ is $\init(f)=f+\mathfrak{m}^{i+1}\in\mathfrak{m}^i/\mathfrak{m}^{i+1}$ where $f\in\mathfrak{m}^i$ but $f\notin\mathfrak{m}^{i+1}$. For an ideal $I\subset R$, let $\init(I)$ be the ideal of $\gr_{\mathfrak{m}}(R)$ generated by the initial forms of elements of $I$. In general, if $f_1,\dots,f_k$ generate $I$, then $\init(I)$ is not necessarily generated by $\init(f_1),\dots,\init(f_k)$ (see for example [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/4134933/1117651)).

In Eisenbud's [Commutative Algebra](https://link.springer.com/book/10.1007/978-1-4612-5350-1) he gives an exercise (5.2) to find a local ring $R$ and $f\in R$ where $(\init(f))\subsetneq\init((f))$. However in the "Tangent Cones" section of Milne's [notes](https://www.jmilne.org/math/CourseNotes/AG.pdf) on algebraic geometry, he states that in the setting where we view $f$ as an element of a polynomial ring, then $(\init(f))=\init((f))$.

I interpret Milne's comment to mean that at any regular point $P$ of a (say quasiprojective) scheme $X$, and for any
$f\in\calO_P$, we have $(\init(f))=\init((f))$ since here $\gr_{\mathfrak{m}}(\calO_P)$ is a polynomial ring. (*Edit:* I now see this is Exercise 4.6.12 in [Bruns and Herzog](https://www.cambridge.org/core/books/cohenmacaulay-rings/938BC2204D8A7C99E2CEBA1695A692A4).) Is there a more general condition on a local ring $R$ for when $(\init(f))=\init((f))$? For example, I think this is true as long as $R$ is a domain, but even here bad things can happen with $\gr_{\mathfrak{m}}(R)$ (e.g. it may not be a domain) so I'm not sure.

Comment: Theorem 1.1 [here](https://www.projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-72/issue-none/Form-rings-and-regular-sequences/nmj/1118785674.full) may be useful.

Comment: @cqfd This is fantastic, please feel free to post as an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $\newcommand{\In}{\operatorname{in}}\In(f)=f+\newcommand{\m}{\mathfrak m}\m^{p+1}$. Then $\In(\langle f\rangle)=\langle \In(f)\rangle$ if and only if $\m^n\cap \langle f\rangle=\m^{n-p}\langle f\rangle$ for all $n\geq 1$.

This is a special case of a more general theorem (Theorem 1.1) proved by Valabrega and Valla in their paper *Form Rings and Regular Sequences* ([Project Euclid link](https://www.projecteuclid.org/journals/nagoya-mathematical-journal/volume-72/issue-none/Form-rings-and-regular-sequences/nmj/1118785674.full)).

The proof of sufficiency is easy: all we have to do is notice that the $n$-th homogeneous component of $\In(\langle f\rangle)$ is $\m^n\cap \langle f\rangle+\m^{n+1}/\m^{n+1}$ and that of $\langle \In(f)\rangle$ is $\m^{n-p}f+\m^{n+1}/\m^{n+1}$.